# How to add items to a dictionary between two methods?

Tags: python, dictionary, global-variables

I'm writing a method that takes in a list and returns a dictionary. This method is to be saved in a separate Python file and imported into Main.py

The method that takes in a list calls another method that's meant to update the global dictionary.

```
global myDict

def addKeyValuePair(listItem):
    try: 
        key = listItem.split(': ')[0].replace('\\','')
        value = listItem.split(': ')[1].replace('\\r\\n','').replace('\\','')
        myDict.update({key:value})
    except:
        pass 

def makeDict(dataList):
     myDict =  {}
     for listItem in dataList:
        addKeyValuePair(listItem)

     return(myDict)
```

From the main method I'm importing the makeDict module and passing it the dataList, but it returns an empty dictionary.

```
from Toolkit import makeDict

finalDict = makeDict(dataList)
```

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Please show the code that actually populates your `dataList`.

Comment: do **not** just wrap a bunch of code in a bare `try-except`!!!